# javascript - display the result of a function as HTML

Tags: javascript, html

so I have this code:

```
function check_total()
  {
   var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    total = 0;

    for (var i=0; i<inputElems.length; i++) {       
       if (inputElems[i].type == "checkbox"){
          total++;
       }
    }
}   

document.getElementById('totalInput').innerHTML = total;
```

Basically, it counts the number of checkboxes in my document.

I would like to have the result (total) displayed in the header of my HTML.

I tried this so far, but didn't work:

```
<span id='totalInput'>default</span>
```

Comment: Place the `total = 0;` outside of `check_total()` or place `document.getElementById('totalInput').innerHTML = total;` inside the function.

Comment: I have tried this but didn't get it to work. I may possibly be doing something wrong.

Comment: This can be achieved via CSS, depending on your use-case: [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/u1ew2zL7/).

Comment: Hi David, impressive, I didn't even expect that to be possible. Thanks for your answer. Appreciate the help for taking the time to review my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a few things you are missing in your code snippet.

First of all, you will need to move your "total" variable outside of the function.  By becoming a global variable, you will be able to use it later in your code.

Secondly, you need to actually trigger this function so that it executes and updates the total variable.  You can do this with

```
check_total();
```

right before the document.getElementById... line

Finally, you could simplify this by using document.querySelectorAll() function.  This will return you an array of all matching elements and you can simply use this as part of your .innerHTML .  By using this, you can replace all of your code by:

```
document.getElementById('totalInput').innerText = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]").length;
```

Finally, on a side note, you should probably use .innerText instead of .innerHTML.  Using innerHTML is always dangerous as someone could inject some javascript here.  In this case, since you don't want to display actual HTML, just use .innerText which does the same thing but with text instead of HTML.

Here is a working example: https://jsbin.com/puhimip/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks for your answer. Appreciate the help for taking the time to review my question. I am selecting your answer as the correct one, because I found it the most simple, to my eyes, to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Your example looks like it should work, other than that in your code, you never return anything from the function. You also need to invoke the function to make it run the calculation.

```
function check_total() {
    var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    total = 0;

    for (var i=0; i<inputElems.length; i++) {       
       if (inputElems[i].type == "checkbox"){
           total++;
       }
    }
    return total;
}   

document.getElementById('totalInput').innerHTML = check_total();
```

Note the `return` statement  at the end of `check_total()`. This enables you to assign the result of that calculation to anything you want (in this case the `innerHTML` property of another element).

As others have suggested, you could also move the total variable out of your function and into what's called *global scope*, but that's not recommended for a whole lot of reasons (see https://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices#Avoid_globals).

Comment: I think I got down-voted because I missed the fact that `total` is declared outside the function. Edited my answer to fix that, and also give advice about avoiding globals.

Comment: Hi Jules, thanks for your answer. Appreciate the help for taking the time to review my question. I have brought that downvote, back to zero, by up voting it.

Answer (score 1):

Try just build up an array from the NodeList that you get by querying for all checkboxes:

```
const countCheckboxes = () =>
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')

const updateHeader = () =>
  document.getElementById('totalInput').textContent = countCheckboxes();

updateHeader();
```

If you wanted to count only the checked checkboxes, you should use `Array.from`

```
const isChecked = input =>
  input.checked

const checkedCheckboxes = () 
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'))
    .filter(isChecked)
    .length
```

Comment: `countCheckboxes` doesn't need the call to `Array.from()`; `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a (non-live) NodeList which itself has a `length` property.

Comment: well spotted. I had it in there assuming i was going to map through eventually. Added a second example showing why.

Comment: I fear I'm becoming *that guy*, but if you use `document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked')` ([`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked), [compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)) you could still avoid `Array.from()` and, as a bonus, skip `Array.prototype.filter()` as well. (Um, sorry).

Comment: Hi Benny, I tried this for querying all the existing checkboxes. It returned "[object NodeList]" instead of the actual integer.

Comment: @FranciscoJurado exactly right! `querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList object. You can get its `length` property to get the total.

Answer (score 1):

The line where you were trying to draw the results of the function into the DOM, wasn't inside the function.  Put that line inside check_total() (and remember to call the function as well.)

```js
function check_total() {
  var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    total = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < inputElems.length; i++) {
    if (inputElems[i].type == "checkbox") {
      total++;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('totalInput').innerHTML = total; // this line was outside the function
}

check_total(); // call the function
```

```html
<div><!-- for demo -->
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="radio">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="text">
</div>

<span id='totalInput'>default</span>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your answer. Appreciate the help for taking the time to review my question.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at Joel's answer too deeply, so don't know if that also solves this.
I think Tyr was definitely onto something, though, and I also wonder if you actually want to know if the checkboxes are checked?

This was a quick n dirty shot at it.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                
                document.getElementById('doit').addEventListener('click', function() {
                    check_total();
                });
                
            });
            
            function check_total()
              {
               var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
                total = 0;

                for (var i=0; i<inputElems.length; i++) {       
                   if (inputElems[i].type == "checkbox"){
                      // do you want to check the checkbox is checked, because it doesn't at the moment?
                      total++;
                   }
                }
                document.getElementById('totalInput').innerHTML = total;
            }   


        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="doit">Do it</button><br />
        <input type="checkbox" /><br />
        <input type="checkbox" /><br />
        <div id="totalInput"></div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Hi Sundance thanks for your answer. Appreciate the help for taking the time to review my question.